# Blender takes high RAM when use high resolution texture

Tags: texturing

My blender file contains cubes, and texture, texture size is quite small ~5MB, but they have high resolution : 10.000 x 10.000

Here is RAM usage before I open blender file
[image]

And here is after open
[image]

Is that a bug ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a bug. The stored image file is compressed while it has to be uncompressed in memory for the viewport rendering in *Material* mode. I'm not entirely certain what bit depth was used internally when textures where loaded in Blender 2.79, but assuming it was 32 bit per color channel then this fits the memory usage quite well: 10000*10000 pixels, where each pixel has four channels (RGBA) with 32 bit each. Since you're having four materials this would result in: 10000*10000*4*4*32 bit = 6.4 GB